# Magento: Bind customer group to domain

Tags: magento, store, subdomain

I have 2 storeviews (B2C and B2B) and some customer groups (B2C, B2B, Reseller) and I need account sharing set to global, but also need to bind my customer groups to their respective storeviews.

This means that a logged in B2B customer should always "stay" in b2b.mydomain.com whereas a B2C customer should always be redirected to the respective content on the b2c.mydomain.com website.

Comment: This needs customization.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible by default, since Magento can distinguish only the website-level and not the Store-level or the Store View-level, for Customers.

Go to Magento Admin panel, and then:-

- System > Configuration
- "Customer Configuration" Group "Account
- Sharing Options" tab
- "Share Customer Accounts" field

In this field, you can only find two options:-

- Global
- Per Website

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you but I need my customer config to stay on a "per website" basis, since customers should belong to their respective "environments" - what I need is a (sub-)domain redirect.